# Passing variables to obejct method on Flight PHP

Tags: php, rest, flightphp

According to the [Flight PHP documentation](http://flightphp.com/learn), to use an object method is by using:

```
Flight::route('/some/route', [$object, 'method']);
```

and to use route parameters is by using:

```
Flight::route('/@name/@id', function($name, $id){
    echo "hello, $name ($id)!";
});
```

I tried to combine both like this:

```
Flight::route('/user/@id', [$object, 'method']);
```

but it doesn't work. Is there any way to pass parameters to an object method?

Answer (score 0):

How about assigning the variables in the closure?

```
Flight::route('/@name/@id', function($name, $id){
    $obj = new Object; // or use a DIC
    $obj->name = $name;
    $obj->id = $id; // or assign these in the constructor
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at [Dispatcher.php](https://github.com/mikecao/flight/blob/master/flight/core/Dispatcher.php) (methods `callFunction` and `invokeMethod`), your use case is supposed to be supported. Parameters should be supported equally well in anonymous functions and in class methods...

Answer (score 0):

This code works for me:

```
function someFunction($id) {
  echo 'id: ' . $id;
}

class SomeClass {
    function method1($id) {
      echo 'Class, id: ' . $id;
    }
    function method2($name, $id) {
      echo 'Class, name: ' . $name . ', id: ' . $id;
    }
}
$object = new SomeClass();

Flight::route('/user/@id', array($object, 'method1'));
Flight::route('/user/@id/@name', array($object, 'method2'));
Flight::route('/fun/@id', 'someFunction');
```

I am not good wit PHP but it's something with callbacks:
https://www.exakat.io/the-art-of-php-callback/